# How do i use a database and java to search for an object if given a description?

Tags: java, mysql, database, search

i have a school project for biology where we need to make something to help us classify animals. We will be given a description with key traits that will define which domain, kingdom etc. will be in. My question is, how could i apply a database to this problem, and can i use java to search through it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that. Plan and implement table structure (one or more tables) and use Java with SQL to retrieve data from the database.

Below there are links to tutorials:

[Java JDBC Tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/)

[SQL Tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp)

And here are samples on this point:

[Real Gagnon Java Database examples](http://www.rgagnon.com/topics/java-jdbc.html)

Comment: I don't understand how I would arrange my tables in my database to make it efficient

Answer (score 0):

You should also use some Object Relational Mapping techniques . This is a good tutorial
[Mapping Objects to Relational Databases: O/R Mapping In Detail](http://www.agiledata.org/essays/mappingObjects.html)

Comment: So each domain or kindom would be it's own object and each phylum would be an object with inherited properties of the kindom and so on? Then each object would be stored in a database?

Comment: It depends on what u want to store in the database.If you have an idea of ER modelling then i think the Entity(s) must be mapped to each object..not the relations.But these are just design principles.If your project is not so big then u dont have to worry about all these